# Remove URL Parameter in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to remove URL Parameter,
but i don't want to use PostBack and Redirect method. It is possible?

E.g

```
Http://localhost/myproject/index.aspx?id=1
```

I will remove the parameter id,
After removal of the parameter,

i want to see this url

```
Http://localhost/myproject/index.aspx
```

Can i do JavaScript or JQuery or asp.net?

Comment: @Aung , why do you want to remove and not do anything??

Comment: This is quite achievable with JavaScript, but what are you trying do here?

Comment: If you want to remove it, than you shouldn't be passing it.

Comment: Why not just use the url hash, eg example.com/page.html#myhash with window.location.hash = 'mynewhash'

Comment: Because of, first page_load i need this parameter. After page_load i don't want to use this parameter. So, i want to remove this parameter. But i don't want to do PostBack and Redirect again. Thanks.

Comment: Just because it's there doesn't mean you have to use it.

Comment: @aung , might be you misunderstood sommthing , there is no harm with the query string , why do you want trouble yourself to remove that don't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.location.replace(url)
```

This should replace the url without loading the page

Comment: @Mattew , don't mind but why do you want to just remove query string and not do anththing , it doesn't make sense , we should tell that to Aung

Comment: @Siri He asked a valid question. This is a valid answer in a vacuum. Maybe what he wants is to post back with a query string then when he is done with it, remove the query string so that he exposes as little about the underlying structure as possible.

Comment: I know it is an old answer but I thought I could use it and have to say that using this **does** reload the page in latest version of Chrome (23) at this time. Given OP used this to replace a clicked href Url and in addition returning false after it, it would explain why the page was only loaded one time for OP. In general though `windows.location.replace(url)` does relaod the page for me in latest version of Chrome at this time.

Answer (score 2):

The URL in the address bar of the browser cannot be changed via code. it can only be changed if you actually navigate to a new location. This means a redirect() or the browser somehow firing a new URL via JavaScript. The only other alternative - as someone mentioned in the comments - is to use a hash for navigation which keeps you on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. Now i doing this style.

```
$('#btnSave').bind('click', function (n) {
     var _url = $(location).attr('href');
     var _arr_url = _url.split('?');
     if (_arr_url.length >= 2) {
         window.location.replace(_arr_url[0]);
         return false;
     }
});
```

Thank you so much all.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i know! this is late, but im really wondering are you using query string??

i don't normally recommend using query string as it imposes security threat,

rather i often use sessions and this is how you use it

to store variables to session.

```
Session["id"] = 1; //or any variable
```

to retrieve it in the other page let's say

```
if (Session["id"].ToString() == "1")
{
//do code
}
```

by this your problem

```
Http://localhost/myproject/index.aspx?id=1
```

will appear as

```
Http://localhost/myproject/index.aspx
```

hope this helps :)